# nginx flask aws 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, flask

My server is running great yesterday but now it returned a 502 error, how could this happen?

In my access.log shows:

```
[24/Aug/2016:07:40:29 +0000] "GET /ad/image/414 HTTP/1.1" 502 583 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
```

In my error.log shows:

```
2016/08/24 07:38:50 [error] 14465#0: *12513 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 123.49.616.74, server: app.example.com.au, request: "GET /ad/image/414 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/ad/image/414", host: "app.example.com.au"
```

This is the result when I run grep:

```
ubuntu    6856  0.0  0.6  56624 12652 ?        S    00:08   0:03 /home/www/carbuzzz_admin/env/bin/python /home/www/carbuzzz_admin/env/bin/gunicorn application:application -b localhost:4215
ubuntu    6865  0.0  1.8 180832 36892 ?        S    00:08   0:00 /home/www/carbuzzz_admin/env/bin/python /home/www/carbuzzz_admin/env/bin/gunicorn application:application -b localhost:4215
ubuntu   14300  0.0  0.0  10464   948 pts/0    S+   08:06   0:00 grep --color=auto -i gunicorn
```

Comment: please share your configuration of nginx for this application.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP status code 502 normally means that the application server Nginx is proxying to is not running. As this is a Flask app I presume this is something like Gunicorn or uwsgi. Check to see if that is running.

I normally use something like Supervisor to ensure that the application server gets restarted automatically if it goes down.

Answer (score 1):

It usually happens when the service isn't running.

So I'd bet your flask application or `wsgi` isn't running.

Comment: How will I know if that is not running? I'm originally a django developer with Apache

Comment: Depends on your conf of nginx, are you using a proxy_pass or uwsgi ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `gunicorn` is not running on your system. Check the status of gunicorn process, and if it is not runningm start the process

Comment: I'm not the one who established this and I'm an Apache user. How do I know if gunicorn is running?

Comment: `Django` and `Flask` application interacts with `Nginx` or `Apache` via `gunicorn`. You can check whether `gunicorn` process is running via `ps aux | grep -i gunicorn`

Comment: Added one more answer. I think your issue is related to that.

Comment: Did you verified what I mentioned in another answer?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your `error` it mentions `123.49.616.74, server: app.example.com.au`, I think within your configuration you have mentioned the IP address of your server. Replace that with your local IP i.e `127.0.0.1`.

Since you are making the request as `127.0.0.1` in your browser and `host` specified in the Nginx configuration is: "app.example.com.au". Due to this connection will be refused by the server.

Comment: that 122 ip address is actually my address. This PC address

Comment: what is 'app.example.com.au'? Trying adding '127.0.0.1' as `server alias` in your `nginx`'s conf file

Comment: Anyway I need to go for now, I'll ask the dev who created this tomorrow thanks!