# After create Docker Image; docker run gives ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, docker

Hi I've a python project contains following structure

in my project directory

```
$ ls
models main.py Dockerfile
```

where models is a directory such that

```
$ cd models
$ ls
model.py utils.py evaluation __init__.py
```

In my `main.py` file I have something like

```
from models import model
```

In my `model.py` file I have

```
from .utils import *
from evaluation import somefile
```

I'm trying to create a docker image and I follow the tutorial with the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.7.2-slim


COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY main.py /
CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

where `requirements.txt` just install `numpy` etc.

running `docker build -t test` is fine and create things accordingly. But when I run `docker run test`. It gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from models import model
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

I assume the there are also error when execute `from .utils import *` and `from evaluation import somefile` at `model.py` even the above error solved.

I think I think I didn't understand how dependency works in Docker and didn't properly solved the dependency. This piece of code works fine when just run in python way such as `$ python main.py` in terminal.

I couldn't find any documents on this part. Any help ? Thanks

Comment: probably is cause by your file structure.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60603593/flask-unable-to-start-server-using-docker-due-to-modulenotfounderror-no-module  I recently face the same issue as well

Comment: @MarkMeyer Hi thanks for the reply. You mean I need to COPY all files/directories within the project directories if my `main.py` has called/imported any of these ?

Comment: Yes, you need to give docker the files you want to use either by copying or adding the directory as a mount point. Also, it doesn’t seem like the imports are correct. Does this work outside the container?

Comment: @MarkMeyer; yes it works well when simply run `$python main.py` in terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is where you are doing `COPY main.py /` in the `Dockerfile`.

You are copying just the `main.py` file.

Instead, replace that line with

```
COPY . .
```

This will move the other folders and files as well.

Comment: Thanks ! yes; that's issue