# Docker run giving 'No module named 'pandas''

Tags: docker, dockerfile, conda

This is my docker file

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/i7d4o1h8/miniconda3:4.10.3p0 
 
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY condaEnv.yml .
RUN conda env create -f condaEnv.yml python=3.9.7
RUN pip install sagemaker-inference

 
COPY inference_code.py /opt/ml/code/

ENV SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY /opt/ml/code/
ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM inference_code.py
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/opt/ml/code/inference_code.py"]
```

When I run docker build with the command `docker build -t docker_name .`, it is successful, at the end I see `Successfully tagged docker_name:latest`

But when I am trying to run the docker image it gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ml/code/inference_code.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

But in the condaEnv.yml file I have the pandas defined as

```
name: plato_vrar
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pandas=1.3.4
  - pip=21.2.4
prefix: plato_vrar/
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62015481/after-create-docker-image-docker-run-gives-modulenotfounderror but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

In anaconda, creating an environment means only the environment is prepared. You need also to **activete** it using `conda activate <ENV_NAME>` then `python` is correctly linked to the anaconda version rather than the system version. Refer to the conda document for more details: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment